# Play random sound file (mp3 file) from preload on mouse click

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

"I want it so when mouseispressed it plays a random sound file from the three soundfiles preloaded already at the top of the code. at the moment i can only play one sound file at a time "

```js
function preload() {
    bird = loadSound('kooka.mp3');
    bird2 = loadSound('galah.mp3');
    bird3 = loadSound('cuckoo.mp3');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(0);
}

function draw() {
    kooka(); 
}

function kooka () {

    if (mouseIsPressed) {

        bird2.playMode('untildone');
        bird2.play();
        bird2.setVolume(0.3);
```

Comment: i changed it to this but it seems to combine sounds simultaneously as opposed to ONE individual sound file being chosen randomly each click.                                                             var birds = [bird, bird2, bird3];
    var rando = random(birds); 

 if (mouseIsPressed) {
  
  rando.playMode('sustain');
  rando.play();
  rando.setVolume(0.3);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of sounds and "select" a random sound from the array:

```js
let sounds = [bird, bird2, bird3];
let randomSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
```

`Math.random()` generates a random number between 0.0 and 1.0. So `Math.random()*sounds.length` is a floating point number >= 0.0 and < `sounds.length`. `Math.floor` gets the integral value which is less or equal the number.

IF the mouse button is pressed multiple times, multiple sounds would be played.
To ensure that just one sound plays  at once you've to note the current sound in variable (`currentSound`) and to verify if the sound has finished playing, before you can start a new sound.
Furthermore use the [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) callback rather than the built-in state variable [`mouseIsPressed`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseIsPressed). The event occurs only one when the mouse is pressed, while the variable is stated as long the mouse is pressed. e.g.:

```js
function draw() {
}

let currentSound;
function mousePressed() {

    let is_playing = currentSound && currentSound.isPlaying();
    if (!is_playing) {

        let sounds = [bird, bird2, bird3];
        currentSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];

        currentSound.playMode('untilDone');
        currentSound.play();
        currentSound.setVolume(0.3);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for help but that plays multiple sound files at once instead of isolating one particular sound file and only playing that one sound at a time. help much appreciated

Comment: hey mate thanks, but when i put that in and click it plays multiple sound files simultaneously, i need it to randomly select ONE sound file and just play that one sound alone until done. cheers for the help

Comment: hey thanks for your help but i also needed the function to be voice activated, any way i invented this dirty method which seems to work :

Answer (score 0):

```
var input;
var mic; 
var bird;
var bird2;
var bird3; 
var bird4; 
var bird5; 
var bird6; 


function preload() {
       bird = loadSound('kooka.mp3');
       bird2 = loadSound('galah.mp3');
       bird3 = loadSound('lyre.mp3');
       bird4 = loadSound('friar.mp3');
       bird5 = loadSound('whistler.mp3');
       bird6 = loadSound('cuckoo.mp3');

    }


function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  input = new p5.AudioIn();
  input.start();


}

function draw() {



     var volume = input.getLevel();
     var threshold = 0.2;
     var regularArr = [bird, bird2, bird3, bird4, bird5, bird6];

    if (volume > threshold) {
    shuffle(regularArr, true);
        var newArr = shuffle(regularArr);
        var beh = newArr[0]; 
        var bef = newArr[1]; 
        var ben = newArr[2];
        var beq = newArr[3];
        var bek = newArr[4];
        var bez = newArr[5];

        beh.playMode('untilDone');
        beh.play(0.1);
        bef.stop(); 
        ben.stop();
        beq.stop(); 
        bek.stop(); 
        bez.stop();  
        print(beh);


}
}
```